# Is using maps of different sizes on the same material harmful?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders

I don't understand if it's an inconsistent practice, but I was wondering whether to actually use in the same shader, of the same material, the following sample maps:

- Diffuse Map 4K
- Bump Map 2K
- Normal Map 3K
- Etc..

Whereas some maps may have different aspect ratios

Does this kill anything in the shader calculation?
Can something obsolete happen in this case?
Is it bad practice for performance?

Comment: If you get what you want is all good. If your maps are way larger than the size they will be on the final render, then is a waste to have them so big. If you see artifacts, blurs or pixelation, then you need bigger maps. All images use resources in your computer, the larger images will use more resources, so it is a matter of using your resources optimally.

Comment: Your answer, it refreshes me, therefore, there seems to be no problems in the technical side of the Software, I think if you are 100% sure of what you are saying, this could be the answer I was looking for.